# IF EXISTS on each group in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Sample Data :

```
| ad_id | ad_type | duration |          page | common | sorter |
|-------|---------|----------|---------------|--------|--------|
|    20 |  center |        2 |               |  false |      0 |
|    21 |    left |        5 |               |  false |      0 |
|    19 |    left |        1 |               |  false |      0 |
|    18 |    head |        2 |               |   true |      0 |
|    17 |  right1 |        4 |               |   true |      1 |
|    16 |  right1 |        5 |               |  false |      0 |
|    22 |  center |        3 |               |   true |      0 |
|    23 |    head |        6 |               |   true |      0 |
|    25 |    head |        2 |               |  false |      0 |
|    29 |    left |        5 |               |  false |      0 |
|    30 |    left |        7 |               |  false |      0 |
|    32 |    head |        4 | 1494573224714 |  false |      2 |
|    33 |    left |        5 | 1494573224714 |  false |      2 |
|    34 |    left |        1 | 1494573224714 |  false |      2 |
|    35 |    left |        9 | 1494066642553 |  false |      1 |
|    36 |    left |       10 | 1494066642553 |  false |      3 |
|    38 |    head |        5 | 1494066642553 |  false |      1 |
```

and desired output :

```
| ad_type | GROUP_CONCAT( duration ORDER BY sorter ASC SEPARATOR ' , ') |
|---------|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|    head |                                                           4 |
|  center |                                                           3 |
|  right1 |                                                           4 |
|    left |                                                       1 , 5 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e67161/1

I'm using the following query:

```
select ad_type,
GROUP_CONCAT( duration ORDER BY sorter ASC SEPARATOR ' , ') 
from ad 

WHERE ad_type='head' AND
 IF( EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM ad where page='1494573224714' AND ad_type='head')
     , page='1494573224714', common=1  )
group by ad_type

UNION
select ad_type,
GROUP_CONCAT( duration ORDER BY sorter ASC SEPARATOR ' , ') 
from ad 

WHERE ad_type='center' AND
 IF( EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM ad where page='1494573224714' AND ad_type='center')
     , page='1494573224714', common=1  )
group by ad_type


UNION
select ad_type,
GROUP_CONCAT( duration ORDER BY sorter ASC SEPARATOR ' , ') 
from ad 

WHERE ad_type='left' AND
 IF( EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM ad where page='1494573224714' AND ad_type='left')
     , page='1494573224714', common=1  )
group by ad_type
```

Is there a way something like IN('head','left','right1','center')

or to perform on all `distinct ad_type`?

The Query I'd used that failed :

```
select ad_type,
GROUP_CONCAT( duration ORDER BY sorter ASC SEPARATOR ' , ') 
from ad 
WHERE 
 IF( EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM ad where page='1494573224714')
     , page='1494573224714', common=1  )
group by ad_type
```

Which returns :

```
| ad_type | GROUP_CONCAT( duration ORDER BY sorter ASC SEPARATOR ' , ') |
|---------|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|    head |                                                           4 |
|    left |                                                       1 , 5 |
```

I want the condition to get applied on each group so that I get results with 'center' ad_type as common=1 etc...

Comment: Are there only 4 ad types? if there's no data for an ad type, what should be in the second column: nothing (empty string), `duration : 0 common : 0`, or something else?

Comment: yes they are 4 ; there has to be data in ad_type ...

Comment: Let me rephrase: in your first example, what values should be in the second column for "center", "left", and "right1:?

Comment: The actual query is `select concat(ad_type,'Ad') as c1,GROUP_CONCAT( concat('<div class="',ad_type,'Ad"  alt=',duration,'><a href="',ad_link,'" target="_blank"><img  src="',img_location,'" width="100%" height="100px"/><span class="w3-small w3-text-grey w3-left">',ad_title,'<br/></span></a></div>') ORDER BY sorter ASC SEPARATOR '') as c2`

which I thought would waste readers time so I simplified it. Previously I was doing it in the program code i.e. select statement in a loop which I read is bad thing to do.

Comment: It would still be helpful to see what results you want to be returned from your first data set.

Comment: I want values for each ad_type in the select table. Like the you have given but with values if the page doesn't exist!

Comment: The answers are going around in circles.  Please provide us a small data set and the desired output.  Sometimes that is better than starting with failing code.

Comment: @RickJames edited again with better clarity,sample data, sqlfiddle link... hope I'm clear this time...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are doing this:

```
select  Outer.ad_type,
GROUP_CONCAT( concat(' duration : ',duration, ' common :',common)
            ORDER BY  sorter ASC SEPARATOR ' , '
            )
    from  ad AS  Outer
    WHERE  IF( EXISTS ( SELECT  1 FROM  ad AS Inner
                    where  Inner.page='1494573224714' ) ,
                           Inner.page='1494573224714',
                           Inner.ad_timeout >= CURDATE() 
             )
    group by  Outer.ad_type;
```

Try it; it should give you an error.

You are really doing

I suspect you are doing this:

```
select  Outer.ad_type,
GROUP_CONCAT( concat(' duration : ',duration, ' common :',common)
            ORDER BY  sorter ASC SEPARATOR ' , '
            )
    from  ad AS  Outer
    WHERE  IF( EXISTS ( SELECT  1 FROM  ad AS Inner
                    where  Inner.page='1494573224714' ) ,
                           Outer.page='1494573224714',
                           Outer.ad_timeout >= CURDATE() 
             )
    group by  Outer.ad_type;
```

This explains your question??

**More**

Here *might* be the first step in getting rid of the `UNIONs`:

```
FROM ad AS ad1
JOIN ad AS ad2  ON ad2.page    = ad1.page
               AND ad2.ad_type = ad2.ad_type)  -- left/right/...
WHERE ( ad2.page='1494573224714'
     OR ad1.common )
```

Comment: Yes I'm doing this however, what I want is that the `IF EXIST` part executes for each group ie. `page='1494573224714' and ad_type='head'` , `page='1494573224714' and ad_type='center'` because `IF EXIST` may be satisfied for `ad_type=head` and  not `ad_type=center` But I want result for each group!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm going to make a few assumptions here:

1. The primary key for `ad` is `page`. If that's not the primary key, then the `pxad` subquery below should have the primary key column(s) instead of 'page'.
2. There are only four possible values for `ad_type` (center, left, head, right1), period. The alternative would be some pages might have (center, head, left, right1) and others might have (head, footer, right1, popup), etc.; that would require additional info to manage.
3. If a given row in `ad` has no entries for a particular `ad_type` (for example, there are rows for `page = '1234567'` with ad_type "head" and "left", but not "right1" or "center"), then we should return all unexpired pages for that ad type.
4. The desired results for your first query should be the one row you show, *plus* the the rows from your second result set for "center", "left", and "right1".

Given the above is accurate, I'd try something along the lines of this (based on the first query you provided:

```
SELECT pxad.ad_type
      ,GROUP_CONCAT( concat(' duration : ',ad.duration,' common :',ad.common)
                     ORDER BY ad.sorter ASC SEPARATOR ' , '
                   ) 

  FROM (SELECT ad1.duration
              ,ad1.common
              ,ad1.sorter
              ,ad1.ad_type
          FROM ad ad1
                 CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'center' as ad_type UNION ALL
                             SELECT 'head' UNION ALL
                             SELECT 'left' UNION ALL
                             SELECT 'right1'
                            ) as AdType
         WHERE IF( EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ad WHERE page = '1494573224714' and ad.ad_type = AdType.ad_type)
                  ,page = '1494573224714'
                  ,ad_timeout >= CURDATE() 
                 )
           AND ad1.ad_type = AdType.ad_type
       ) pxad
 GROUP BY ad_type;
```

(NOTE: code is untested)

The subquery labeled `pxad` will check for records with your desired `page` value, and each of the four possible `ad_type`s. Where it finds matches, it uses those; where it doesn't, it returns all unexpired pages for the ad_type.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time; The problem is still the third assumption which is what the problem was before; The `IF EXIST` should test each `distinct ad_type` and then return the condition i.e. `ad_timeout >= CURDATE()` Also page is foreign key or blank or a word or a null . I've edited the question with another query which I'm currently using. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Yes, and that's what it's doing. If we find a page with the ID you specify, we return that page and the `ad` rows for any of the four `ad_types` we do have a row for, plus a rows with all `ad` values set to `NULL` where no such row exists; if there is no page whatsoever with the desired ID, we return the same as above for all pages that haven't expired.

Comment: Unless you mean you want your check done explicitly for each page and ad_type: If there's a page 1234 with ad types "head" and "center", then return the info for page 1234 for "head" and "center"; for "right1" and "left" return the info for all unexpired pages? Please clarify

Comment: I supply a `page` I want if exist to check where `page` = 'blah' where ad_type= 'center' if not then return other condition... Then do the same for next ad_type kind of `union` like in my question

Comment: Updated based on your last comment, which clarified the desired results.